# array in C/C++ for AVR keeps appending

Tags: c++, c, global-variables, avr

In C, I have an array waiting to receive bytes from a sensor, save in a buffer, and then print out like this:

```
unsigned char responseFrame[300];

int main(void) {
   UART_init();
   while(1) {
       receive(responseFrame);
       myLog(responseFrame, sizeof(responseFrame));
   }
}
```

I populate the array by doing the following:

```
void receive(unsigned char *rcv_buff) {
    uint8_t recv_data;

    for (int i=0; i<300; i++){
            USART1_Flush();
        rcv_buff[i] = USART1_RX();
    }
}
```

Then I print out what's in the buffer using the following:

```
// Logs this output to the serial port; used for debugging
void myLog(unsigned char *msg, int size) {
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        USART0_TX(msg[i]);
    }
}
```

This prints out the array, but when another iteration of bytes is received, everything is appended so let's say I receive {0xFF, 0xFF} first my output for the first iteration is:

```
0xFF 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00 ... 0x00
```

But upon the next iteration let's say {0x0A, 0x0A} is received instead, in the output I see this:

```
0xFF, 0xFF, 0x0A, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00 ... 0x00
```

NOTE: The ellipses is just saying there's more 0x00s which are printed out until we basically reach the size of the array.

Why is this appending and not overwriting from the start of the array?

Here's my USART0_TX and USART1_RX functions:

```
void USART0_TX(uint8_t myData) {
    // Wait if a byte is being transmitted
    while( !(UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)) );
    // Transmit data
    UDR0 = myData;
};
uint8_t USART1_RX(void) {
    // Wait until recv buffer is full
    while( !(UCSR1A & (1<<RXC1)) );
    // Return recvd data
    return UDR1;
};
```

Here's the code I'm using to flush my USART1 RX:

```
//USART1 flush, clears USART1 buffer
void USART1_Flush( void )
{
    unsigned char dummy;
    while ( UCSR1A & (1<<RXC1) ) dummy = UDR1;
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about AVR, but maybe the data behind `USART1_RX` is buffered and doesn't auto-flush. That would mean you're just reading the same data again with any new data appended until you flush it.

Comment: As smocking pointed out, that could very well be the case. Also to note, if your using a modern compiler, the volatile keyword is not needed, as the compiler will most likely ignore it, same goes to the keyword register.

Comment: Why write `&responseFrame[0]`? `responseFrame` would work just as well and is cleared to read.

Comment: Where are you getting your documentation on USART1_RX? From what I can see that is an interrupt vector, not really something you should be polling unless you are doing some strange things behind the scenes.

Comment: @Justin USART1_RX is justa custom function I'm calling to get data out of the register. I've editted the question to include it up above.

Comment: @charliehorse: you're right. obviously as a novice, I'm doing it the "hard way" :P

Comment: @smocking: I'm including my flush up top, but it's still giving me the appending...

Comment: And you're not getting any rx overruns? Perhaps you should clear RXEN1 while you're transmitting?

Comment: I don't think this will help your problem, but you might consider moving `USART1_Flush();` to just above the `for` loop, so it doesn't get called while you're actively receiving data.

Comment: Is it possibly a bug on the reception side? Maybe in the tool you're using to view this data? You should be getting exactly 300 bytes of data back in each frame — have you confirmed that you are? Or maybe your sensor is configured to send old data with following frames? Do you have a datasheet or description of how the sensor works?

Comment: @mrb Yea, didn't really help. I'm using a PN532 breakout board from adafruit whose datasheet is listed here [PN532 DataSheet](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/pn532um.pdf) From the read, it shouldnt' be sending out the same data, unless you send a NACK.

Comment: @Michael: I suppose I could RXEN1 --- I dont need to do this when I send data from my PC to the chip though so it seems suspicious that I'd need to do that for the sensor to the chip. But, I'll get back to you after I've tried that.

Comment: Another method I tested was that in the `for` loop, I directly said `USART0_TX(USART1_RX());` and this transmits properly, without any appending or repetition. Is this something to do with the my `recv_buff` pointer or the way I'm addressing the array?

Comment: @codedawg82: This is mainly why I was asking about overruns. If you transmit each byte immediately there's a very short delay between each rx call, while when you use the myLog function there's a relatively long period of time where you transmit all 300 bytes while having RXEN1 enabled, meaning new data could arrive from the sensor and fill up the rx buffer. That might not be the problem in your case, but it could be worth double-checking.

Comment: @johnathon The `volatile` keyword is not and cannot be ignored by any compiler for a system where concurrent/parallel execution is possible; considering interrupt service routines a special case thereof. Likewise, depending on the target architecture, a compiler really *should not* ignore the `register` keyword but consider it a hint for optimization; especially with an architecture like the AVR µ-controllers. Therefore, avr-gcc honours both keywords.

Comment: Hi everyone, I wanted to update what I ended up doing here. This is more a work-around then truly "solving" the question. Instead of using the pointer parameter in my `receive` command, I directly referenced the variable like so --- `responseFrame[i]=USART1_RX();` Then using the `myLog` function worked appropriately. (OTHER SPECIFICS: I use ATMEL's AVRStudio 6.0 and the default compiler which I believe is AVR-GCC)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your function called "Flush" is really a "Poll" function, looking for a character to appear (this would be normal usage, wait for the char to appear). The logic where you use RXC1 appears inverted. Try looking at this quite professional looking AVR driver (that has a poll option just as you are doing):

[usart.c](http://www.raphnet.net/divers/anemometre/windmon_avr/usart.c)

Another nicely commented polled driver (and small with lots of comments): [avr uart driver](http://www.nerdkits.com/library/codelib_uartterm/)